# Why does the CompletableFuture allOf method do a binary search?

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future

I wanted to know if the `allOf` method of `CompletableFuture` does polling or goes into a wait state till all the `CompletableFutures` passed into the method complete their execution.
I looked at the code of the `allOf` method in `IntelliJ` and it is doing some sort of binary search.

Please help me to find out what the `allOf` method of `CompletableFuture` actually does.

```java
public static CompletableFuture<Void> allOf(CompletableFuture<?>... cfs) {
    return andTree(cfs, 0, cfs.length - 1);
}

/** Recursively constructs a tree of completions. */
static CompletableFuture<Void> andTree(CompletableFuture<?>[] cfs, int lo, int hi) {
    CompletableFuture<Void> d = new CompletableFuture<Void>();

    if (lo > hi) // empty
        d.result = NIL;
    else {
        CompletableFuture<?> a, b;
        int mid = (lo + hi) >>> 1;

        if ((a = (lo == mid ? cfs[lo] :
                  andTree(cfs, lo, mid))) == null ||
            (b = (lo == hi ? a : (hi == mid+1) ? cfs[hi] :
                  andTree(cfs, mid+1, hi)))  == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();

        if (!d.biRelay(a, b)) {
            BiRelay<?,?> c = new BiRelay<>(d, a, b);
            a.bipush(b, c);
            c.tryFire(SYNC);
        }
    }
    return d;
}

/** Pushes completion to this and b unless both done. */
final void bipush(CompletableFuture<?> b, BiCompletion<?,?,?> c) {
    if (c != null) {
        Object r;

        while ((r = result) == null && !tryPushStack(c))
            lazySetNext(c, null); // clear on failure

        if (b != null && b != this && b.result == null) {
            Completion q = (r != null) ? c : new CoCompletion(c);

            while (b.result == null && !b.tryPushStack(q))
                lazySetNext(q, null); // clear on failure
        }
    }
}

final CompletableFuture<V> tryFire(int mode) {
    CompletableFuture<V> d;
    CompletableFuture<T> a;
    CompletableFuture<U> b;

    if ((d = dep) == null ||
        !d.orApply(a = src, b = snd, fn, mode > 0 ? null : this))
        return null;

    dep = null; src = null; snd = null; fn = null;

    return d.postFire(a, b, mode);
}
```

Comment: It builds a balanced binary tree and then waits bottom up for each nodes' children to finish. You haven't posted enough code to say if it does so by polling or wait state, and I'm too lazy and in bed to look at it myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't do a binary search -- it's building a *balanced binary tree* with the input futures at the leaves, and inner nodes that each complete when its two children have both completed.

For some reason that is not apparent from the code, the author of the code must have decided it was most efficient to consider `allOf(_,_)` between exactly two futures to be his primitive operation, and if he's asked for an `allOf(...)` between more than two futures, he's manufacturing it as a cascade of these binary primitives.

The tree should be *balanced* for such that no matter what the last future to complete is, there will only be a small number of levels left to collapse before the future at the top can complete. This improves performance in some situations, because it ensures that as much work as possible can be handled *before* we're completely done, at a point where (if we're lucky) the CPU might just be sitting idle, waiting for something asynchronous to complete.

Balancing the tree is done by having the *topmost* inner node have about as many leaves under its left child as under its right child -- so both children get about half of the original array, and then the code recursively builds a tree from each half of the array. Splitting in halves can look a bit like the index calculations for a binary search.

---

The basic structure is obscured slightly by special cases that appear to be designed to

- use an optimized code path with fewer allocations when some of the original futures are already completed, and
- make sure that the result of `allOf(_)` with exactly *one* element will return a *fresh* `CompleteableFuture`. For most purposes it would work to just return that single element, but the author must have wanted to ensure that users of the library can rely on the object being fresh, if they are using them as keys in hash maps, or other logic that depends on being able to tell the output from the inputs, and
- have only one `throw new NullPointerException();` by using `?:` and inline assignments instead of honest `if` statements. This *probably* produces slightly smaller bytecode at the expense of readability. Cannot be recommended as a style to learn from, unless you personally pay for the storage cost of the resulting bytecode ...

Comment: Your description is somewhat clear but I need a little more low-level details if possible to see the big picture. Why there is a need for the complete binary tree of futures? Can you explain the behaviour of allOf() method ? Is CompletableFuture an event-based library. I mean when these future leaves complete their execution they create an event for the parent future to wake up.

Comment: @limo_756: I'm afraid I don't really understand what you're missing, and why you _need_ particular low-level details. Are you unaware how to _use_ `CompleteableFuture` in general? In that case you ought to read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) rather than try to understand it from the source code alone.

Comment: The reason to settle on a completion method for two futures, might be simply because it’s already there, as backend of `thenAcceptBoth`, `thenCombine`, etc. The reason to enforce the return of a new future, is that anyone can complete a future, e.g. invoke `cancel` on it, but also `complete` with a value, and it would be a semantic error if that had an effect on the input future(s). The reason to make the tree balanced, is that it allows completion of branches in parallel, but also to minimize the risk of a stack overflow when completing the dependent futures.